# C Program - " Exception thrown at 0x0FFC0F18 (ucrtbased.dll) " getting this error while debugging

Tags: c

I tried debugging the lines of code one-by-one and got to know that it shows the error on line " if (strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2) == 0) ".

[Error Image - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxmxS.jpg)

Please check the link above.
I marked the line with red box.
No idea why am getting that error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>

//STRUCTURE
struct date_struct
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
int day2;
int month2;
int year2;

};

//USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
float input(struct date_struct takein);
char tarik(struct date_struct printer);
void header();
//STRUCTURE-VARIABLES
struct date_struct date = { 0,0,0 };

void header()
{
printf("*-*-*-*DATE_STRUCT*-*-*-*");
printf("\n\n");
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
main()
{

//HEADING
header();

//FUCNTION CALL-OUT
input(date);

//TERMINAL_PAUSE
system("pause");
}

float input(struct date_struct takein)
{
printf("Enter the Date(1) : \n");

printf("Day : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.day);
printf("\n");

printf("Month : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.month);
printf("\n");

printf("Year : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.year);

printf("\n");
printf("\n");

printf("Enter the Date-(2) : \n");

printf("Day : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.day2);
printf("\n");

printf("Month : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.month2);
printf("\n");

printf("Year : ");
scanf_s("%d", &takein.year2);
printf("\n");

tarik(takein);

if (strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2) == 0)
{
    if (strcmp(takein.month, takein.month2) == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2) == 0)
        {
            return(0);
        }
        else
            return(1);
    }
    else
        return(1);
}
else
    return(1);

}

char tarik(struct date_struct printer)
{
switch (printer.month)
{

case 1:
    printf("Date(1) : January %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 2:
    printf("Date(1) : February %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 3:
    printf("Date(1) : March %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 4:
    printf("Date(1) : April %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 5:
    printf("Date(1) : May %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 6:
    printf("Date(1) : June %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 7:
    printf("Date(1) : July %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 8:
    printf("Date(1) : August %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 9:
    printf("Date(1) : September %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 10:
    printf("Date(1) : Octomber %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 11:
    printf("Date(1) : November %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;

case 12:
    printf("Date(1) : Devember %d, %d\n\n", printer.day, printer.year);
    break;
}

switch (printer.month2)
{

case 1:
    printf("Date(2) : January %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 2:
    printf("Date(2) : February %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 3:
    printf("Date(2) : March %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 4:
    printf("Date(2) : April %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 5:
    printf("Date(2) : May %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 6:
    printf("Date(2) : June %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 7:
    printf("Date(2) : July %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 8:
    printf("Date(2) : August %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 9:
    printf("Date(2) : September %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 10:
    printf("Date(2) : Octomber %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 11:
    printf("Date(2) : November %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;

case 12:
    printf("Date(2) : Devember %d, %d\n\n", printer.day2, printer.year2);
    break;
}

return;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2)`  Can't use `strcmp` for `int` -->`takein.year == takein.year2`

Comment: `main() {` is invalid. Implicit `int` return type is not standard anymore. Main should be either `int main ( void )` or `int main (int argc, char **argv)` compatible. And `main` _has_ to return an int, you're not returning anything, which is technically UB

Comment: thnx alot for the help was bit confused xD

Comment: Do not post links or images.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: While I agree with the rest, the standard allows to omit an explicit `return 0` in `main` only. If control reaches the end of main, it is supposed to `return 0` implicitly. (I agree it is better style to have that explicit `return 0;`, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2)` is wrong, the type of `takein.year` and `takein.year2` is `int` and not `char*`.

Replacing

```
strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2)
```

by

```
takein.year == takein.year2
```

Should do the job, but there may be other issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcmp(takein.year, takein.year2)
```

Says compare the strings store at addresses `takein.year` and `teakein.year2`.

And what do we have in `takein.year` and `teakein.year2`?

Those are just normal integers and *not* addresses. Here `strcmp` is trying to access the memory locations outside of it's allocated process memory space and that's why the exception.

Use `==` to compare `int`s.

Use `strcmp` to compare strings **only**!

---

Also what is `scanf_s("%d", &takein.year2);`?

I don't believe `scanf_s` is the standard library function. Does this code compile and gets link successfully ?

---

Also if you are using string library functions then include `<string.h>` though most probably the default linking library contains the function definitions of most common functions. (e.g. `libc` in Linux)

Comment: [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) is a Microsoft thing.

Comment: I use Visual Studio for debugging my code. If I use scanf it ask me to use scanf_s  instead of scanf. That's the reason :P

Comment: And thnx for taking interest in my question :)

Comment: @Eddy Oh I meant `<string.h>`

Comment: @rootkea I added that before and it created tons of problem for me. I use visual studio for debugging my code. If you add <string.h> then it ask you to follow some visual studio stuff (like I told you before you have to use scanf_s instead of scanf - do not relate this with <string.h>).
Code works fine when I do not use <string.h> :P

Answer (score 1):

you have been fully answered by fellows, i just want to add some improvement to your code:

```
// global variable;
const char *months[] = {
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
               };


// instead of using switch case 
    printf("Date(1) : %s %d, %d\n\n",months[printer.month-1], printer.day, printer.year);

    printf("Date(2) : %s %d, %d\n\n", months[printer.month2-1],printer.day2, printer.year2);
```

Comment: I'm new in C and I didn't read " Pointers " chapter yet anyways thnx for the advice :)